# Json views not displaying in json format, instead displaying in web view

Tags: views, 8

I created a json view for a CCK.

I am trying to display the view on my webpage. The data is rendered as a web page. But i need something like exact json response.

Here is the screen shot
[image]

Please help to find out the solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya i got the solution. Just un_check the Viewa API[image]

Hope this will help some one

Comment: where is this option ?